# matplotlib scatter animation; original plot always on screen

Tags: python, matplotlib

My animation is not working as expected:

With blit = True I have the original function on screen always and without it I have every update of the function, neither of which is desirable.

Any help greatly appreciated, Im using Anaconda collection of SciPy packages on Win7 with spyder IDE

I've tried playing with the arguments in animation.FuncAnimation() but no luck, I've bare boned the code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation



def run():

    x = range(100)
    y = range(0, 1000, 10)
    x2 = range(50)
    y2 =range(0, 500, 10)
    fig = plt.figure()
    scat1 = plt.scatter(x, y)


    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_plot, blit = True)
    plt.show()

def update_plot(i):
    x = range(i, 100+i)
    y = range(i, 1000+i, 10)
    scat1 = plt.scatter(x,y)


    return scat1,


run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting an `init` function is [required "to set a clean slate"](http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/simple_anim.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation

def run():
    fig = plt.figure()
    pathcol = plt.scatter([], [])

    def init():
        pathcol.set_offsets([[], []])
        return [pathcol]

    def update_plot(i, pathcol):
        x = range(i, 100+i)
        y = range(i, 1000+i, 10)
        pathcol.set_offsets([(xi, yi) for xi, yi in zip(x, y)])
        return [pathcol]

    plt.xlim(-10, 200)
    plt.ylim(-100, 1500)
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_plot, 
                                  init_func=init, 
                                  interval=0,
                                  blit=True, fargs=[pathcol])
    plt.show()

run()
```

- Also, inside `update_plot` be sure to use `pathcol.set_offsets` to modify the
  *existing* `PathCollection` instead of calling `plt.scatter` again. Modifying
  the existing `Artist` will improve animation speed.
- `init` does not take any arguments, but we want `init` to refer to the `pathcol` created in `run`. Therefore I moved `init` inside the `run` function so that inside `init` Python will find `pathcol` in the enclosing scope of `run`.
- `update_plot` is passed `pathcol` since `fargs=[pathcol]`, so `update_plot` could be made a function outside of `run`. But since `init` is nested inside `run`, for symmetry I decided to put `update_plot` inside `run` too.